# Iphone 4 Verizon. I cannot find Itunes Radio

Tags: itunes, iphone, itunes-radio

I updated my Iphone 4 and I was playing Itunes Radio for the first couple of days. All of a sudden it disappeared and I no longer have access to Itunes Radio. It is no longer in my music app. I live in the US so this cannot be an US only issue.

Please help

Comment: nevermind. I killed the running app and restarted it and it was there.

Comment: See here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102958/48249